# No adapter attached; skipping layout error in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

Recyclerview in my Fragment is giving me this error but I couldn't figure it out. There are lots of questions about this issue but none of them solved my problem so far.

Here is a piece of code from my fragment:

```
 @Override 
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
          Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    initCollapsingToolbar();

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(2, dpToPx(10), true));
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    prepareSectors();

    try {
      Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.cover).into((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.backdrop));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return view;
  }
```

Comment: what is the error?post it

Comment: @SriMaharshiManchem I think the error is clear:

`E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout`

Comment: Are you sure your `adapter != null`?

Comment: @DavidMedenjak I'm pretty sure it is not null

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it is. Mind double checking?

Comment: See my answer below. You did not initialize adapter before setting to recyclerview. Hope this will work for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not create an `instance` of your `adapter` before setting it to `RecyclerView`.

```
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(2, dpToPx(10), true));
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    // Your adapter initialization here
    adapter = new YourAdapter(getActivity(), ....);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**UPDATE:**

Get `LayoutInflater` from passed `context`. Update your `SectorAdapter` code portion as below:

```
public Context mContext; 
public List<Sector> sectorList;
LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

public SectorAdapter(Context mContext, List<Sector> sectorList) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.sectorList = sectorList;
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.sector_card, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}
```

Try moving your `RecyclerView` codes to `onViewCreated()`

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    sectorList = new ArrayList<>(); 
    prepareSectors(); 

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(2, dpToPx(10), true)); 
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator()); 

    adapter = new SectorAdapter(getActivity(), sectorList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: I initialized my Adapter inside OnCreate method of the Fragment. After your suggestion I moved it to OnCreateView but still getting the same error

Comment: have you passed getActivity() as context.... Use adapter = new YourAdapter(getActivity(), ....);

Answer (score 0):

There is no any code for your adapter. Thus you need to implement the adapter and pass the instance to the recyclerView.

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager ....
 ....
// Your adapter initialization here
adapter = new someAdapter(....);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This will help you!